# WCF web service response blank on window server 2019 but the same release works normally on server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2019, iis-10, wcf

We have a website that migrated from windows server 2016 to 2019 recently.
After the migration, infra crew found all the aspx pages shows blank and after digging into it, we found it's since the web service it is calling response blank.

If I link to RestServiceImpl.svc of a server 2016 with the same version of web service.
[image: correct greeting/guiding page]

I will see the greeting/guiding page as expected.
However, if I link to the same version host on 2019 server. It will be all blank.
[image: blank page]

When check with source code, it's empty too.
[image: source code view empty]

If I call a get method, server 2016 will response me correct xml but 2019 will reponse empty with http 200.
[image: http 200 but 0 data]

The eventlog we are using to trace the web service error does not record anything.
I add TraceListener to web.config but it does not write any svclog to the directory

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I have added full control to the application pool identity to `c:\log\Traces.svclog`
Don't know if when it's 200, it won't generate any log?

We also check if it's since http activation feature is not installed but it has been.
[image: http activation feature is installed]

We are running out of idea here, any suggestion is welcomed.

If I add `<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />`
then the web service can response correctly on local, so I think it has something to do with IO permission or CAS policy. But not sure what specific thing is missing/misconfigured.

Comment: A service that has no logging, no debugging, no source code, no documentation. This is not a realistic question. You may want to add more detail, such as the configuration of the pre-production environment test servers, and the definition of "migration".

Comment: Migration here means publish the same version of web service to a server that theologically has the same setting but the platform is 2019.

Comment: What kind of configuration usually we can provide for this kind of issue to dig deeper? I don't know why the log mechanisms are not working.

Comment: If a service does nothing on a vanilla Windows Server 2019 test system with no other roles/features/products installed, the vendor/developer should be engaged.

Comment: Use Microsoft's example IIS-hosted WCF service to see if that also does not work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/deploying-an-internet-information-services-hosted-wcf-service

Comment: Let your infra guys show you what IIS role services they installed. What they gave you so far is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's since the .NET Trust Level has a lower level at the new server.
In IIS manager > Connections > YourServer > .NET Trust Levels, changing the trust level to Full (aligned with the level of the old server) fixed the problem.
[image]